# Does the number of popovers affect page load speed?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a page with possibly 2000 popovers using bootstrap 4.

Does the number of popovers affect the page speed? I don't know enough about javascript frameworks to understand whether loading 10 popovers has the same effect as loading 2000. That is what I want to understand.

The contents of the popovers is loaded by javascript.

Comment: popovers? You mean like modals ?

Comment: @WilomGfx I mean: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/

Comment: The number of HTML elements on a page affects "page speed" inasmuch as the browser must load them all into the DOM. Since presumably a "popover" is part of the DOM, yes, they affect performance. As with most performance questions though, the best answer is to test it yourself.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan So if I understand it correctly the only overhead is to the DOM. The javascript does not actually on load time do something with all of the popovers. So I am right in thinking, sorry for noob status here, that it *does* parse the DOM at page load?

Comment: That's what page loading is; parsing the DOM, loading other assets as they are referenced. Note that there will also be JS overhead, since bootstrap (or whatever) will need to keep track of all of those popovers. I was just saying that at the very least, loading 2000 popovers will take more memory than 10. There is likely to be other overhead. Again, testing this yourself, in your specific situation, is the only way to be sure.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks. That would be an answer. Could you point to a link that explains how to test the memory usage and javascript overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I have used to minimize the impact of things like this is to use a single popover/modal/dialog/etc.. and then changed it's contents right before it is shown. This way you don't have 2k extra elements in the DOM that 99% of the time are doing nothing.

I worked up an example of bootstrap popover's using the `selector` option and delegation by enabling it on a parent element. It appears that they may have any overhead issues worked out.

If you inspect the body of the example, you will see a single popover div appended to the body when it is shown and then removed when it hidden.

```js
$(function() {
  var $table = $('#test');

  for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr />');
    for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      var td = $('<td />').attr({id: (i * 100) + j, tabindex: -1});
      row.append(td);
    }
    $table.append(row);
  }
  
  $table.popover({
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    trigger: 'focus',
    selector: 'td',
    content: function() {
      return '<p>This is my id: ' + $(this).attr('id') + '</p>';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="test">
</table>
```

Comment: Could you expand on how that works if I have 2k different elements I want to add the popover to? Genuinely asking because of a lack of knowledge. How does this reduce the number of DOM elements?

Comment: I've never used bootstrap popovers. Trying to work out an example for you. I'll edit when I have it.

Comment: Great skills! Thank you for an excellent example and a good understanding of my question.

Comment: Would this also work on a table that is not constructed using javascript?

Comment: Yes I think it would. One nice thing about this method is none of those nasty `data-blah` stuff in your markup html.